# WPF Style Trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers

I am trying to get a row in a datagrid to turn red if the value of a checkbox within the datagrid is true.  Any ideas?  Here is what I have so far.  I am currently turning the columns red if the mouse rolls over the row.

Comment: You forgot to include the code that you reference.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this blog post by Vincent Sibal](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/09/16/wpf-datagrid-styling-rows-and-columns-based-on-header-conditions-and-other-properties.aspx). Sibal gives several code examples of what you're trying to do and he also provides a good sample project you can download to see the source.